# Multi-Domain SSL setup with pointers

Tags: ssl

I have one server, with DirectAdmin, with the main-domain DomainA.com. Other local domains, like DomainA.co.uk, DomainA.fr and DomainA.de are pointed (alias) to this main-domain. When someone visits a local domain, it's internally redirected to DomainA.com, where some code recognizes the domain an shows the website in the local language without redirecting the visitor to DomainA.com.

This is working fine, but now I want to use SSL on all the domainnames. Is this possible with the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a certificate with subject alternative names or use for a solution like CloudSSL from GlobalSign: https://www.globalsign.com/cloud/